# Calvin Candie's "dimples in the skull" theory

Tags: realism, django-unchained

In Django Unchained, Calvin Candie tells Django and Dr. Shultz a theory about the dimples in the skull of human beings. He says that due to the location of these very dimples which is different in case of Whites and African Americans, their behavior is different.

Is this theory, purely imaginary and used just for making a good story or does it hold any scientific weight?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Calvin's just a follower of [phrenology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrenology) which is essentially an out-dated and discredited 'science' of analyzing bumps on people's heads to determine the attributes of the brain within.  The idea being that the different parts of the brain have various specialized jobs.  So a lump in an area associated with laziness means that person is lazy because their brain (and so their skull) was shaped that way.

Comment: *"which is essentially an out-dated and discredited 'science'"* - Of course you’d say that, you have the brainpan of a stage coach tilter! ;)